# Ajax, change variable after load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, load

i have this code:

```
<?php $i=12;
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
    <div id="prueba"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function loadXMLDoc()
     {
         var i = "<?php echo $i; ?>";
         var xmlhttp;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else {
             xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         {

             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                 {
   document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
                 } 
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?i="+i,true);
          xmlhttp.send();

      }
      window.onclick =loadXMLDoc;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my load.php file is this:

```
<?php
    $i = $_REQUEST["i"]; 
    echo $i;
    $i=$i+1;
    echo "<?php $i=".$i."?>";
?>
```

When I click on the page it loads load.php and it echo out the value of $i. I add 1 to the value of $i, and I want that when I click the second time the value be 2, and so on, adding 1 to the $i value. However it always output 1. The output is 111111111 and am looking to get 1234567 etc. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is it xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?i="+ii,true); or it may be xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?i="+i,true); please check once

Comment: sorry its xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?i="+i,true);

Comment: please edit your code and write there. it's confusing

Comment: show this code on fiddle. it's not working at all at my end

Comment: i have edit it. When I click it, it appends a 1 to the div.

Comment: Actually it's not working at my end that;s why i said to  put it on fiddle.

Comment: Can you show me your whole code?

Comment: you want to do it using javascrip and php both??? you can do it using javascript only.

Comment: thats all the code, well a simplified version, but in the end thats what I need. When run in xamp it does work.

Comment: What happen is that it have to request data from the server side. This is a simplified version of what am trying to achieve.

Comment: Never used jsfiddle before, so I cant find where to set the load.php file.

Comment: There is php tag inside another php tag in load.php

Comment: but i echoed it. Thats my try to make the $i of the html file the same as the load.php file.So that's where i need help

Answer (score 0):

try this. I have modified your code

```
          <?php $i=12;
    ?>
    <html>
        <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="prueba"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var i = "<?php echo $i; ?>";
         function loadXMLDoc()
         {
             var xmlhttp;
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
             else {
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             {

                 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                     {
       document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                     } 
              }
              i=i+1;
              var   pruebaInnerHtml=document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML;
pruebaInnerHtml=pruebaInnerHtml+i;
              xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?ihtml="+pruebaInnerHtml,true);
              xmlhttp.send();

          }
          window.onclick =loadXMLDoc;
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And load.php file is this:

```
<?php
    $i = $_REQUEST["ihtml"];
    echo $i ; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but what I need is ajax. Am trying to make a dynamic scrolling content, and that content is on the server so javascript is not enough for my problem.

Comment: You want to calculate all things on server side?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function loadXMLDoc()
 {
     var i = document.getElementById("pruebaVal").value;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("pruebaVal").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php?i="+i,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  window.onclick =loadXMLDoc;
</script>    
</head>
<body >
<input type="hidden" id="pruebaVal" value="1">
<div id="prueba"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is load.php

```
<?php
$i = $_REQUEST["i"]; 
$i=$i+1;
echo $i;
?>
```

I have moved the ajax code to Head part from body part. And using hidden variable to initialize the `var i` and also to store ajax response for further increments.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only php to check "i" you can use $_SESSION:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["i"]=0;
    ?>

<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

    <div id="prueba"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function loadXMLDoc()
     {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","load.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    window.onclick=loadXMLDoc;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in load.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["i"] = $_SESSION["i"]+1;
    echo $_SESSION["i"];
?>
```